# Display UIViewController as a popover

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to display a UIViewController as a small popover over an other UIViewController.
The UIViewController should be display modal, but not take the whole screen.
It should just show up on a lower third of the screen...

Can somebody point me to a tutorial or give me some hints to start on this?

I googled for over one hour, but could not find anything, that helps me :(

Thanks for your help,
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered that this question is still unanswered ... You have multiple options to achieve such a thing running on iPhone:
Depending on the situation, I think I would just go with a UIViewController subclass loading from a NIB that you configured to show a screen-sized view with the backgroundColor property set to [UIColor clearColor]. Add whatever subviews you want to display as a popover to that view at the position you want (e.g. lower third of screen). You can then present the view controller modally with the UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve to fade it in and even use the background view to intercept touch events to dismiss the modal view.
Another possibility would be to just add the popover's view controller's view as a subview to the main view controller's view. You can use UIView's animation class methods to animate the transition.

Answer (score 1):

this might help.
you have to declare popOverController in the header and make it a property as well as synthesize it.

```
if([self.popOverController isPopoverVisible])
{

    [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

UINavigationController *favNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                  initWithRootViewController:favoritesView];

//favoritesView is an outlet to the VC Favorites
//make a nav controller with the root view an outlet to the view you want to present.


self.popOverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                           initWithContentViewController:favNav] autorelease];

    [popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:revealFavorites permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //revealFavorites is the button i press to show the favorites popover
favoritesView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 310, 320); //set the frame




if (![self.popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [favNav release];

}

}
```

Comment: You are using UIPopoverConttoller, but this is iPad only... I want to Build something similar for iPhone. But I want to show the view allways on the same position.